# JSON to AS3 Object issue

Tags: javascript, json, actionscript-3, flash

I am new to JSON to AS3 Objects and am having issues trying to create an AS3 object that I can reference. Here is the JSON:

```
{
demo: {
    Male: {
        21-30: 2,
        31-40: 0,
        41-50: 0,
        51-60: 0,
        61-70: 0,
        71-80: 0,
        81+: 0
        },
        Female: {
        21-30: 7,
        31-40: 0,
        41-50: 0,
        51-60: 0,
        61-70: 0,
        71-80: 0,
        81+: 0
        }
    },
    days: 0
```

}

Here is the parsing code:

```
        var JSONRequest: URLRequest =  new URLRequest();
    JSONRequest.method      = URLRequestMethod.POST;

    JSONRequest.url         = "https://www.urlhere.com;
    var loader: URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, handleResponse);
    loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler);
    loader.load(JSONRequest);

    function handleResponse(event:Event):void{
        var returnData:String = loader.data;
        var parsedData:Object = JSON.parse(returnData);
    }
```

I have tried and successfully looped through the object with for loops, but I don't want to have to do that, I want to be able to access the data as an object or array by accessing the properties in dot syntax. Object[0].property etc...

The really tricky part is that I don't know how large or how deep the data is nested. The one I added here is simple.

Here is more like what I will be getting:

```
    {
    products: {
        Home & Garden: {
            Kitchen: {
                202: {
                    brand: "OXO",
                    description: "12 piece locktop container set",
                    descriptionLong: "Prepping, cooking and cleaning",
                    listPrice: "36.32",
                    sku: "925776",
                    upc: "719812032528"
                    },
                    238: {
                    brand: "Excalibur",
                    description: "Excalibur 2400 4-Tray Dehydrator",
                    descriptionLong: "Dehydration is the healthiest",
                    listPrice: "168.54",
                    sku: "947741",
                    upc: "029743240009"
                    },
                    352: {
                    brand: "Nostalgia",
                    description: "OldFashioned Kettle Corn Maker",
                    descriptionLong: "With the Nostalgia Electrics ",
                    listPrice: "35.49",
                    sku: "925843",
                    upc: "082677300218"
                    },
                    370: {
                    brand: "Joseph Joseph",
                    description: "Nest Plus Measuring (Set of 5 Cups - Multi Coloured)",
                    descriptionLong: "Nest™ Cups are a range of 5",
                    listPrice: "2.46",
                    sku: "926733",
                    upc: "5028420400342"
                    },
                    605: {
                    brand: "Nostalgia",
                    description: "Margarator-Frozen Drink Maker",
                    descriptionLong: "Mix up great-tasting margaritas",
                    listPrice: "140.68",
                    sku: "925851",
                    upc: "082677135889"
                    }
                    },
                Housewares: {
                    206: {
                    brand: "Dyson",
                    description: "Dyson DC44 Animal",
                    descriptionLong: "DC44 Animal has a detachable",
                    listPrice: "406.51",
                    sku: "922846",
                    upc: "879957006362"
                }
    }
}
```

I will also add that I can request the formatting of the JSON I am receiving, so if there is a better way to format the data coming from the server, I am open to that.

Any help would be great.

Comment: With the code you posted, you can already do parsedData.products['Home & Garden'].Kitchen... etc. Which problem are you having?

Comment: None of the JSON you've posted is valid, and you've not closed the `"` quotes on the 4th line in your ActionScript.

Comment: *"I don't know how large or how deep the data is nested"* means you don't know the schema beforehand. If you have no idea of the data's schema, the only way to retrieve what you want is looping through every branch.

Comment: @Vesper Well, he *could* create a "dot syntax parser" that would enable him to look through the JSON using a text input at runtime, but I don't think he should, or even want to do that.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to be able to access the data as an object or array by accessing the properties in dot syntax.

Use  `JSON.stringify` and a `replace` callback before the parse call to rename the keys so you can access them via dot notation:

```
function newkey()
  {
  return "key" + Number(Math.random() * 1000).toFixed() + RegExp.$1
  }

//Stringify JSON
var foo = JSON.stringify(parsedData);

/*
Replace numeric keys with a random number without replacing the delimiter
Replace spaces with underscores
*/
var bar = foo.replace(/\d+("?:)/g, newkey).replace(/\s/g,"_")

//Parse resulting string
var baz = JSON.parse(bar);
```

**References**

- [JSON - AS3 API Reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/JSON.html)